# How to convert symfun into string in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I simply did this

[image]

This results in variables like this

[image]

I want to convert this ySol into a string something like this "C1*exp(t^2/2)"

As I am making a GUI application I want to display this solved equation value in a TextBox

I tried

```
num2str(ySol)
compose(ySol)
cprintf(ySol)
sprintf(ySol)
```

Comment: Please copy-paste your code into your question, don’t post screen shots of code (or any text). https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7328782

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
char(ySol)   % to get the following char   array 'C1*exp(t^2/2)'
string(ySol) % to get the following string array "C1*exp(t^2/2)"
```

Noticed that this is an undocumented matlab feature, it could be removed at anytime.